Molecular dynamics and chemical reactions
I am familiarizing with the book on molecular dynamics, and as far as I understood the calculation in it is based on Newton's laws and potential fields (which act by forces on particles). Can molecular dynamics emulate chemical reactions between molecules? (For example H+H+O = H20) Or are there methods that allow to do it? Do they have to be methods of quantum mechanics?  Are there packages like Amber for molecular dynamics of chemical reactions in this case?

First, there are two types of molecular dynamics simulations: classical (MD) and ab initio molecular dynamics (AIMD). The difference between those two lies in how you calculate the potential energy. In AIMD you get the potential energy for each particle via quantum mechanical methods, usually DFT, and the ensembles are implemented just as in MD. At the DFT accuracy level, chemical reactions can be simulated; however, this comes at the cost of using computationally expensive DFT methods.
In the case of MD, the potential energy is calculated using mathematical expressions, like Lennard-Jones (LJ) or the Coulomb potential, which is specifically parametrized for the system you want to simulate. For example, the TIP4P model combines both LJ and Coulomb potentials, introducing a phantom atom positioned between the atoms of the water molecule. There are various flavors of TIP4P, each tailored to represent different properties or phases of water, including liquid-gas and solid states. The problem with TIP4P is that it cannot represent the formation and breaking of chemical bonds. This is a characteristic of non-reactive potentials. On the other hand, there are reactive potentials, such as Tersoff and ReaxFF, that can actively form and break bonds. However, it's important to remember that there are no universal potentials in molecular dynamics (MD), and their effectiveness can be highly system-dependent. Take me for example, when I was learning MD, I attempted to simulate water interacting with carbon nanotubes using ReaxFF for the C-H-O interactions. The problem is the specific version of ReaxFF I used was parameterized for combustion, which led to completely wrong results. The moral of the story, MD can simulate chemical reactions between molecules, but you need your potential to be parametrized for that reaction, and for the system conditions you want (temperature, pressure, etc.).
Following current trends, machine learning has recently been applied to generate potentials with DFT accuracy, enabling simulations of larger systems over longer time scales. This might be of interest to you, and I recommend checking out this article.
In summary, you can simulate chemical reactions using MD, but it's essential to have the appropriate potential.

Thanks for detailed answer

Matheus is right about Newtonian MD and AIMD, but there's a third method that's faster than AIMD, where you would treat most of the system using Newtonian physics, and treat only the chemically active site of interest with quantum methods, which saves on compute and makes it more feasible.
This is called QM/MM for "quantum mechanics/molecular mechanics" and has been around for a decade, but I think it's really starting to ramp up as methods are more fully developed. I haven't used AMBER in a while but just found this implementation of QM/MM in a tutorial, meaning that some of the more robust MD systems are finally able to treat things like enzymatic reactions. Pretty cool!
https://ambermd.org/tutorials/advanced/tutorial2/index.php

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
